# Can I lock Centos yum updates to 1 specific base version?

Tags: centos, locking, yum

I'd like to lock down my Centos 6.3 x86_64 server to only receive updates released for that base version, i.e. 6.3.
Is this possible? If so, how?

I do not want it to upgrade kernel to future base versions such as 6.4, 6.5, etc.

Reason for this is that some of our corporate apps run on 6.3 and we can't take a chance of them breaking ......for now!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is multi-part.

Generally, I believe, once newer versions of CentOS are released the older versions stop getting updates. So saying "I want to only get updates for a specific version" really means "I don't want updates anymore" as far as I know.

That being said, you can likely prevent any new kernels from being installed by adding `exclude=kernel*` to your yum configuration (in `yum.conf`).

Additionally, if all you care about is disallowing automatic *usage* of newer kernels when they get installed then you can change the value of `UPDATEDEFAULT` in `/etc/sysconfig/kernel` to `no` to prevent that.

I should not that the above is all from experience with and inspection of my CentOS 5 machine so it might or might not be identical for CentOS 6.

And lastly, if you really did want to restrict system upgrades to only things available in a given minor version you would need to find a CentOS mirror which had broken out 6.X directories and them manually point your yum repository configurations at those repositories. (Most default repositories update to the latest version when it is released, for the reasons I mentioned at the start about updates to old releases as far as I know.)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll look at lab testing updates to check for compatibility issues I think.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something similar for Centos 7.8, I modified the files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo`.

In each file you'll find info for a repo of the format:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

And in all cases you'll want to set `enabled=0`

Next you can create your version locked repos, in `CentOS-Vault.repo` you'll find repos pointing to `http://vault.centos.org/...` URLs for all previous minor releases, e.g.

```
# C7.2.1511
[C7.2.1511-base]
name=CentOS-7.2.1511 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=0

[C7.2.1511-updates]
name=CentOS-7.2.1511 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=0

[C7.2.1511-extras]
name=CentOS-7.2.1511 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=0

[C7.2.1511-centosplus]
name=CentOS-7.2.1511 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=0

[C7.2.1511-fasttrack]
name=CentOS-7.2.1511 - Fasttrack
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/fasttrack/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=0
```

However, you want to lock to the current version which will not exist in this file, so copy the block as above, and modify the version to match your target minor version. e.g. `C7.2.1511` to `C7.8.2003` and don't forget to change `enabled=0` to `enabled=1`.

You can leave your copied and modified repos in this file, or create a new .repo file in the same directory.

Reboot your system to enable the changes.

---

Note that if you have installed more repositories, e.g. `yum install centos-release-scl`, instead of disabling the repo, you'll want to modify the `baseurl=` part of the config to point at the equivalent `http://vault.centos.org/` URL.

Note that I am not an expert, this is working for me but may not be best practice. I have however not found a better solution online.